# Set multiple TextBlock inside a GridViewColumn

Tags: wpf, gridviewcolumn

I'm trying to set two `TextBlock` inside a `GridViewColumn`:

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding PlayerA}" />
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" />
  </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

but I get that the content is already set, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataTemplate` property can have only ONE child. You are setting TWO children, the two `TextBoxes`.

You must include the `TextBoxes` in a common container.

If you want a simple horizontal concatenation, you can write this:

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <TextBlock Text="blabla1"/>
      <TextBlock Text="blabla2"/>
    </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

If you want an equal distribution of the `Width` among the two `TextBoxes`, you can write this:

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="1"/>
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="2"/>
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

There are many WPF containers, it depends on what layout you want to achieve, but the rule is: **DataTemplate must contain only ONE element**.